# Font SIze not Consistent (Percentage)

Tags: css

I have a base size in my html of 62.5% and I multiply my headers' font-sizes accordingly. When I inspect it in my Chrome: different h2 headings have the same font-size, but they appear in diff. sizes on my screen. From my understanding the font sizes (with %) depend on the font-size of html. But anyways the parent containers are also the same width.

```
 html {
    font-size: 62.5%; }

  h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    text-align: center; }

  h1 {
    font-size: 250%; }

  h2 {
    font-size: 187.5%; }

  h3 {
    font-size: 125%; }

  h4 {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em; }
```

I figured out, that there are two font-sizes in the parent elements, which are crossed out. If I deactivate them in my developer window it still affects the size of the headers. Interesting to see.

But I think I had a misunderstanding, I thought if I have a parent defined in the css like
`div h1`, the font-size of the parent affects the size. But it seems that every parent font-size has an effect on its child elements. That makes working with %, like in the article below, in my humble opinion useless, because you are not able to set a hierarchy for the fonts. Or am I wrong? So the best way would be to use rems everywhere to get consistent font-sizes?

Comment: As far as i'm aware, that's not valid css. Are you bac using  or LESS, etc?

Comment: Its SCSS but I guess that's quite readable code for CSS users and there is a bigger community. Also the problem is a CSS one. That's why I posted it with the CSS tag.

Comment: if it's a css problem, could you post the css? If it's a sass problem, could you post a workable demo showing this issue?

Comment: If you have a CSS problem, there is no point in bringing Sass into the question at all.

Comment: You are right. I just didn't save an unminified version, thus I had to create one first. I didn't assume it is so abstract to read. Now I guess people understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

In html tag set font size in percentages, in body tag set to 1em, and other tags use em units

Comment: Or use `rem`s instead of `em`s, to avoid applying multiple relative calculations.

Comment: This article recommends using % rather than ems:
http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

But I also tried to set html in %, body to 1em and h2 to 4em (for the test). Unfortunately the problem is still there. It's marginal but it messes up the design.